# Not Getting Printout whenever i published code in IIS server

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, printing

I am developed automatically print out application in WEB API  when I run this code in the visual studio its working fine but I have published this code in IIS server then I am not getting the printout before the print process code will be working but print process code will not working

hear my print process code is

```
                    Process proc = new Process();
                    proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
                    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @" /t /h " + "\"" + folderpath + filename + "\"" + " " + "\"" + printerName + "\"";
                    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    proc.Start();
                    proc.WaitForInputIdle();
                    proc.Kill();
```

Comment: "...not working..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: Acrobat Reader does not support running in headless mode: https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/acrobat-reader-dc-command-line-options/td-p/7150551 - you're also probably violating the Acrobat Reader EULA.

Comment: but it's working well in visual studio 2013 without getting any error issues

Comment: You can learn why from https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Did you see any access denied error when you monitor the behavior in process monior?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon. Besides, have you tried to change application pool identity to local system?